# Building 8051 application under DOS

Tags: ms-dos, cross-platform

I'm trying to rebuild some 8051 code from 25 years ago and the documentation is a bit sketchy. It is all MS-DOS based and I'm running it from the Command Prompt on a Windows XP machine.

I've managed to run the assembler and create the objects but I'm having difficulty with the linker (rl51.exe).
The only file I have is the file below which is described as a command file.
It's not a .bat or .cmd file (continuation character is a "&") and it looks like it has been created to overcome the 128 character limit on parameters to rl51.exe. But I've not been able to figure out how to call the file and create the linked application.

Does anybody have any idea of how to do this?

Thanks

```
REM Command file to link EB01
REM;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
REM                                                                 ;
REM   MODULE NAME         : EB01 LINK FILE                          ;
REM   IDENTITY            : EB01.LNK                                ;
REM                                                                 ;
REM;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

rl51 ..\obj\EB0100D.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0101C.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0102C.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0103D.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0104D.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0105F.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0106B.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\AB0107A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0108E.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\BB0109A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0110D.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0112B.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0113B.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0121B.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0122A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0123A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0124C.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0125A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0130A.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB0140B.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB01DC.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB01CDD.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB01KC.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB01MKA.OBJ, &
     ..\obj\EB01CSD.OBJ &
     to EB01D &
     pr (EB01D.M51)

EXIT
```

Comment: I'm not going to close this as off topic - but I feel like retrocomputing might be a better site for this. Also considering 8501s are a different architecture would this even work?

Comment: If you can't find documentation for your old crosstools, then consider looking at this Open Source cross-environment to see how these tools perform the same task: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcu8051ide/ Note that there's also a "Windows XP/7" version of this software package that could replace what you have.